# Adding breadcrumb text as body class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add the category of the product being viewed as a body class. The website is built on bigcommerce.com and as far as I can tell this isn't possible with their variables.

So I'm trying to pull the category from the breadcrumbs and add that as the body class.

I have my breadcrumbs

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel Breadcrumb" id="CategoryBreadcrumb">
    <ul class="last">
        <li><a href="http://legacy-food-storage.mybigcommerce.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li>Other Products</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I have my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topCategory = $('#CategoryBreadcrumb ul li:nth-child(2)').text.replace(/\s/g, '-');
  $('body').addClass(topCategory);
});
</script>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you find a fix for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should of use `text()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topCategory = $('#CategoryBreadcrumb ul li').last().text().replace(/\s/g, '-');
  console.log(topCategory)
  // $('body').addClass(topCategory);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Block Moveable Panel Breadcrumb" id="CategoryBreadcrumb">
    <ul class="last">
        <li><a href="http://legacy-food-storage.mybigcommerce.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li>Other Products</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```